# Ruby on Rails, Resque

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, background-process, resque

I have a resque job class that is responsible for producing a report on user activity. The class queries the database and then performs numerous calculations/data parsing to send out an email to certain people. My question is, should resque jobs like this, that have numerous method (200 lines or so of code), be filled with all class methods and respond to the single ResqueClass.perform method? Or, should I be instantiating a new instance of this resque class to represent the single report that is being produced? If both methods properly calculate the data and email it, is there a convention or best practice on how it should be handled for background jobs?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both strategies are valid.  I generally approach this from the perspective of concurrency.  While your job is running, the resque worker servicing your job is busy, so if you have N workers and N of these jobs running, you're going to have to wait until one is done before anything else in the queue gets processed.

Maybe that's ok - if you just have one report at a time then you in effect will dedicate one worker to running the report, your others can do other things.  But if you have a pile of these and it takes a while, you might impact other jobs in your queue.

The downside is that if your report dies, you may need logic to pick up where you left off.  If you instantiate the report once per user, you'd simply need to retry the failed jobs - no "where was I" logic is required.